# Data Sync between 2 tables in Oracle Database

Tags: c#, oracle11g, synchronization

i have 2 tables namely table1 (id, name, address, contact_number, gender) and table2 (id, name, contact_number) used Oracle 11g XE.

in table1 i have data : (1, john, Jakarta, 123345, male), (2, reina, Bandung, 568955, female). i wanna have  data based on table1 to table2 like (1, john, 123345), (2, reina, 568955).

After table1 has new data like (3, alfiano, Meda, 789654, male), table2 doesn't duplicate data exist (john and reina) but just add the alfiano data value.

when i query trigger

```
select trigger_name, trigger_type, triggering_event, trigger_body from all_triggers where table_name = 'TABLE1'
```

[image: this is my trigger]

in this case i have a button to execute the sync. but i don't know the code anymore. i am using C#.

```
private void btnSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // i don't know the code
    }
```

how can sync data between those tables?
anyone can suggest me?

Comment: aminvincent, we need more information here. Do you have a trigger on table1` that updates `table2`? If so, please add the trigger code to your question.

Comment: @EdGibbs in this case i have a button to axecute and i don't know the code....i am using C#...can u suggest me?

Comment: To check if there are any triggers on your table1 use this query: `select trigger_name, trigger_type, triggering_event, trigger_body from all_triggers where table_name = 'TABLE1'`

Comment: I'm sorry @aminvincent, but there isn't enough information to answer your question. If you have any more information please post it.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov i have checked trigger in my table1, but didn't find anything,..it means that i don't have a trigger??

Comment: @EdGibbs i still don't understand what is trigger in oracle?? any suggest reference that i can learn??

Comment: aminvencent, what @DmitryEgorov and I are trying to figure out is how `table2` is updated from `table1`. It could be a trigger that executes when you update `table1`, or it could be some other code. If you know how `table2` is updated we may be able to help.

Comment: @aminvincent: I suppose so. Then you've got you data populated from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following trigger definition in order to reflect table1's data into table2 automatically:

```
create or replace trigger table1_fill_table2
after insert on table1
for each row
begin
    insert into table2
        select :new.id, :new.name, :new.contact_number
        from dual;
end;
/
```

Note, however, that you should avoid the code which did only partial `table2` modifications. This is presumably `btnSync_Click`.

Please refer to Oracle documentation for further information on triggers:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020 -- for generic usage description

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374 -- for trigger definition syntax